# Django only rendering a single variable

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I request a page that calls the following view:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader
from mainsite.models import Courses

def individualCourse(request, course_short):

    c = Courses.objects.get(short=course_short)
    t = loader.get_template('course.html')
    cont = Context({
        'course_short': c.short,
        'course_title': c.title,
        'course_start': c.startDate,
        'course_end': c.endDate,
        'course_fees': c.fees,
        'course_description': c.description,
        'course_content': c.content
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(cont))
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Courses(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    short = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    startDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    endDate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    fees = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    content = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return  self.title, self.short, self.startDate, self.endDate, self.fees, self.description, self.content
```

course.html:

```
<html>
<head><title>Course</title></head>

<body>

<p>{{ course_title }}</p>
<p>{{ course_short }}</p>
<p>{{ course_start }}</p>
<p>{{ course_end }}</p>
<p>{{ course_fees }}</p>
<p>{{ course_description }}</p>
<p>{{ course_content }}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want it to display all the details for that particular course, but when it renders on the page, it only displays the title of the requested course. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: first of all why not you are using the render_to_response

Comment: I'm working through the Djangobook and this is how it's shown. Is there a particular reason why render_to_response would work where this doesn't? Or is it just for clarity/efficiency?

Comment: This should work. Are you sure you are calling to the correct view? I'm not sure this matters or not but your `__unicode__()` method of `Courses` model should return a unicode string rather than tuple/list.

Answer (score 2):

try this one 
i dont know the return type specifier for a date field, it needs some correction but should look something like this

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s (%s %s %s %d %s %s %s)' % (self.title, self.short, self.startDate, self.endDate, self.fees, self.description, self.content)
```